# add view to customview and resize that

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i have a customview that extend from FrameLayout:

```
public class FanView extends FrameLayout {

private static final String TAG = FanView.class.getSimpleName();

private List<FanItem> fanItems = new ArrayList<>();
private float openRatio = 0f;

public FanView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLayout(" + changed + ", " + left + ", "  + top + ", " + right + ", " + bottom + ")");
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    Log.d(TAG, "End onLayout");
}

@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    final float index = getChildCount() - indexOfChild(child) - 1;
    final float height = child.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    matrix.setTranslate((float) (-index * 1.1 * (height/2) * openRatio), (float) (index * height * openRatio * 1.2));
    return true;
}

public void setOpenRatio(float r) {
    this.openRatio = r;
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = getChildAt(i);
        view.invalidate();
    }
    invalidate();
}

public void setFanItems(List<FanItem> fanItems) {
    this.fanItems = fanItems;
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i < fanItems.size(); i++) {
        int fanItemIndex = fanItems.size() - i - 1;
        FanItem fanItem = fanItems.get(fanItemIndex);
        View fanView = inflate(getContext(),
                fanItemIndex == 0 ? R.layout.fan_item_header : R.layout.fan_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) fanView.findViewById(R.id.fan_view_item_title);
        textView.setText(fanItem.getTitle());
        addViewInLayout(fanView, i,
                new LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

}

in xml layout i use this custom view with width and height wrap_content.
when i add view to that custom view not show this views,
because custom layout not change it's size.
how to say to custom view that change it's size

Comment: Also post the code of fan_item.xml. Please check if height and width is wrap_content fan_item.xml.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fan_item_background"
    android:textDirection="rtl">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fan_view_item_title"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ersfsdf"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</FrameLayout> @SimpleCoder

Comment: Try giving height some dp value too for TextView inside FrameLayout.

Comment: i want this custom view was dynamic size.
for example, dropdown list
@SimpleCoder

Comment: Change size dynamically using layoutParams of widgets.

Comment: how
@SimpleCoder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195471/discussion-between-mehdi-mousavi-and-simplecoder).

Comment: Just posted possible code . Check answer. if seems fit please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide valid size to inflate the items at first. Give at least one element to acquire size after layout inflation. You can change the size of items using layout params.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:background="@drawable/fan_item_background" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textDirection="rtl">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fan_view_item_title"
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:text="ersfsdf"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

To change the size dynamically try something like this .

```
// Gets linearlayout
FrameLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.framelaut);// or any layout
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your current code probably needs another constructor

```
public FanView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
```

Comment: I Remove that for summary